# Asus N56V: Nvidia Geforce Gt not enabled

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, asus

The video works with the integrated card without swithcing to Nvidia Geforce Gt

Using the info-center I can see

in PCI, an Nvidia Non-VGA unclassified device (0x00)

in Opengl, an Intel Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller

Description of my framework:

===========================================================

Machine: Asus N56V laptop

===========================================================

Software

- Kubuntu 12.04 amd64
- kernel (3.5.0.5-generic) and drivers from xorg-edgers fresh X crack ppa

===========================================================

Hardware and problems

- after installation do not boot - SOLVED using boot-repair
- every couple of hours the system freezes - SOLVED using 3.5 kernel
- keybord FN keys - NOT WORKING
- Keyboard backlight - NOT WORKING
- Nvidia GEFORCE GT - NOT USED glxgears says 60 fps
- Ethernet Atheros card - SOLVED install alx driver
- external subwoofer - SOLVED adding options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4

==========================================================

Solutions

see the asnwers to the 162047 and 166261 questions

==========================================================

Comment: Kubuntu 12.04 is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.